# Libgdx rotating to angle with Vector2s

Tags: java, libgdx, rotation, angle

I am trying to make the player rotate and face a target position, and have encountered a problem I am unable to fix.

When the ship is rotating towards the target position, when it reaches directly below the target position, it goes crazy and moves left and right while going downwards (away from the target position) and eventually off the screen.

I do not want to limit the screen as it will look weird when it is slowly rotating if it is near the screen limit. In this case if I do limit the screen, it will still get stuck at the bottom as it keeps turning left and right. I uploaded an image on imgur to try to better explain my problem.

Yellow is the direction ship is moving (it is rotating towards the target position but will cross the red line), Green is an imaginary vector towards the target position, Red is another imaginary vector which represents whenever the ship goes crazy. When the green line goes on top of the red line, the ship begins to bug out and go out the screen.

```
public void ai() {
    switch (playerArrived()) {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            pTargetPos.set(ran(0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth()), ran(0, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()));
            System.out.println("Player Destination Reached: " + pPos.x + "," + pPos.y + " Moving to new point: " + pTargetPos.x + "," + pTargetPos.y);
            break;
    }
    turn();
    move();
    ePlayerBody.set(pPos.x, pPos.y, pWidth);
}

public int playerArrived() {
    if (pTargetPos.x < pPos.x + pWidth && pTargetPos.x > pPos.x - pWidth && pTargetPos.y < pPos.y + pHeight && pTargetPos.y > pPos.y - pHeight) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

public float ran(float low, float high) {
    return (float) (Math.random() * (high - low + 1)) + low;
}

public void move() {
    pVel.set(pTargetPos.x - pPos.x, pTargetPos.y - pPos.y);
    pVel.nor();
    pVel.x *= sMaxSpeed + Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    pVel.y *= sMaxSpeed + Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    pVel.setAngle(pNewRotation + 90);
    pPos.add(pVel);
}

public void turn() {
    pRotation = ((Math.atan2(pTargetPos.x - pPos.x, -(pTargetPos.y - pPos.y)) * 180.0d / Math.PI)+180.0f);
    pNewRotation += (pRotation - pNewRotation) * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    System.out.println(pRotation+"    "+pNewRotation);
}
```

I uploaded an image on imgur to try to better explain my problem

[image]

Comment: First question: The javadoc for `Math.atan2()` says that the first argument is `y` and the second argument is `x`. You seem to be calling it in the opposite order... are you sure this is what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your ship is directly below, and just a little bit to the left of, the target, then the call `Math.atan2(pTargetPos.x - pPos.x, -(pTargetPos.y - pPos.y))` will return a value very close to π/2. When your ship is directly below, and just a little to the right of, the target, that call will return -π/2. As you cross the red line, your direction will flip-flop by 180 degrees (π radians). That's why it's "going crazy".

You need to figure out a better way to determine what angle you should turn towards. I'd offer suggestions on that, but I'm still unclear on exactly what behaviour you are expecting.

Comment: What I have here is a player ship that flies by itself, it has a target position (random x, random y) on screen and starts moving towards that location. It has a rotation speed so there for there is a steering behavior to it. What I had was the velocity moves the ship forward and the turn sees what angle needs to be corrected to start faacing the target point and turns the player towards the point. I have tried other methods of getting the angle, but because libgdx y is upside down, it was to no avail.

Comment: So do you find that, aside from the flip-flopping issue, the code works properly? I'm not overly familiar with libgdx but it looks to me like there's a lot of strangeness in your code. For example, `move()`: you calculate the vector to the target, normalize it, multiply it by a speed factor and then overwrite the whole thing by calling `setAngle()`? Why not just call `setLength()` with your speed factor and `setAngle()` with your direction?

Comment: And then take `turn()`: All you really need to do is figure out if the target is to the left or to the right of your current heading (create a `Vector` to the target, and use `angle()` to compare that `Vector` to your `pRotation`), and call `pRotation.rotate()` with a positive or negative value, accordingly. If you agree with this, I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: If I do not use setAngle, the ship rotates immediately towards the targetposition, with setAngle, there adds a ship steering feeling to it. Edit: I will give it a try, Thank you sir

Comment: I have posted the answer, thank you very much for your help! it helped me solve the it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
    public void turn() {
    pRotation = ((tPos.y - pPos.y) / (tPos.x - pPos.x) * 180.0d / Math.PI);
    pNewRotation += (pRotation - pNewRotation) * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
}

public void move() {
    pVel.set(pDir);
    pVel.nor();
    pVel.x *= sMaxSpeed + Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    pVel.y *= sMaxSpeed + Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    pVel.setAngle(pNewRotation + 90);
    pPos.add(pVel);
}
```

Comment: this.pDir.set(tPos.x - pPos.x, tPos.y - pPos.y);